# Wheel generated inconsistently compared to installation

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, setuptools

I have the following files:

```
setup.py
problems/
    __init__.py
    sometimes_included/
        file.txt
```

`__init__.py` simply contains:

```
import os
with open(os.path.join(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "sometimes_included"), "file.txt")) as f:
    print(f.read())
```

And `file.txt` is just some dummy text.

The file is in a repo at https://github.com/ysangkok/packaging-problems

When I `pip3 install https://github.com/ysangkok/packaging-problems/archive/master.zip`

and then `python3 -c 'import problems'` it doesn't work, (the txt file was not installed).

But if I clone the git repo and `python3 setup.py install --user`, it works.

How can I achieve consistent behaviour without listing `problems/sometimes_included` as a package in `setup.py`. This directory is not a package, it shouldn't need a `__init__.py`. And given that it works when not using wheels, I am wondering if there is a way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a file `MANIFEST.in` with `include problems/sometimes_included/file.txt`

Comment: That would ensure the file is included in the sdist but not in the wheel, and the wheel is what pip uses.

Comment: It's seems like this is not necessary. If I change `package_data` to reference `sometimes_included/file.txt` instead of `problems/sometimes_included/file.txt`, I can install using wheels, or the old way.

Comment: I tested it on his repository and it included the file in the wheel.